# Ubuntu 20.04 audio issues only sound in laptop speaker and not in jack

Tags: sound, headphones

I have rog-Strix-15-GL503GE and my laptop produces no sound through headphone and headset. Both the headphone and headset is working fine. After the new update it's not working. I have Realtek ALC 892 Codec. And I have tried all the pulseaudio and pavucontrol and alsamixer fixes which are shown in online. So I have no idea what to do more. Help me out. THanks in advance.